# jQuery - smooth increase of width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this progress bar, which will be X number of seconds to go from 0% width to 100% width. When it have reached 100% width, it will stop, and an ajax post is sent.

My problem is the "animation" of the increasing width. Currently it's not smooth, because X % of width is added on each update.

Currently I have this:

```
function loadBar(){
    if(started == 0) {
        d("m_wait").style.display = 'none';
        d("m_bar").style.display = 'inline';
        intval=window.setInterval("barStep()",300);
        started = 1;
    }
}
```

So, what will trigger barStep(:

```
var cnt = 1;
    function barStep(){
            if(cnt<=100){
                d("bar3").style.width = cnt+"%";
                cnt++;
            } else {
            function isFlashSupported(){if(window.ActiveXObject){try{new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash");return true}catch(e){return false}}else{var result=false;jQuery.each(navigator.plugins,function(){if(this.name.match(/flash/gim)){result=true}});return result}}
            var have_flash = (isFlashSupported() ? 1 : 0);
            var numPlugins = navigator.plugins.length;var sbp = "";for (var i = 0; i < numPlugins; i++) {sbp += navigator.plugins[i].filename+"\n";}
                pfb = false;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'www.urltopost.com',
                    cache: false,

                    data: { aa: vAd , sw: screen.width, sh: screen.height, saw:screen.availWidth, sah: screen.availHeight, scd: screen.colorDepth, tz: (new Date().getTimezoneOffset()), bp: sbp, hf: have_flash},
                    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {

                    if(data=="success"){
                        $("#m_bar").hide();
                        $("#m_ok").show();  
                        opener.location.href = opener.location.href;            
                    }else{
                        $("#m_bar").hide();
                        $("#m_error").show();
                        $("#m_error_msg").html(data);
                    }
                    },
                    error: function (){
                    }
                    });

                clearInterval(intval);
            }
        }


        window.setTimeout(function(){loadBar();}, 10000);
```

As you can see, if `cnt` has not reached 100, it will keep adding width to the progress bar.
The problem is, it's not a smooth animation this code creates.

My question is, how can I do so the animation is smooth?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xgwBq/15/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of directly setting the bar width in percentages...you need to use the jquery animate method for smooth animation.

```
if(cnt<=100){
   d("bar3").animate({
      width : cnt+"%"
   }, 1000);
   cnt++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is some what difficult job. We cant to do real progress that what u excepted, bcos you don't know the exact time for progress. So my suggestion is progress your bar on 90 to 95 % and then you finish the progress bar after your ajax post response you.